# Clear the cache for a jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on sharepoint edit form, and we can define a function named `PreSaveItem()`, which will get executed before the form is submitted to the server, as follow:-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function PreSaveItem(){
    var result = true;
    var status=$("select[id*='Status_'] option:selected").text();
    if (status == "Closed") {
        var analysis = $('input[id^="Analysis_"]').val().trim();
        alert(analysis);
        alert(Date.now());
        if (analysis == "") {
            alert("Please Enter Analysis before closing the item");
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
</script>
```

The above script will show and alert() if the users change the status to "Closed", while they left an Input field named "Analysis" empty. but seems i am facing a caching issues when the script is reading the updated value for the `$('input[id^="Analysis_"]').val().trim();`. as follow:-

1. let say i changed the status to "Closed" + i left the "Analysis" input field empty
2. click on save
3. then i will get this alert correctly `alert("Please Enter Analysis before closing the item");`.
4. then after getting the alert, i entered some text inside the "Analysis" input field >> click on Save again.
5. then i will get the same error. and the `alert(analysis);` will still show the old empty value, while the `alert(Date.now());` will show updated date-time.. so seems the `var status=$("select[id*='Status_'] option:selected").text();` is being cached?
   also the weird thing is that the `$("select[id*='Status_'] option:selected").text()` is not being cached ...

Comment: .val is didfferent than .text .val is the value attribute

Comment: nah, i seriously doubt cache is related to your problem. .text and .val do not have any built-in caching mechanisms and it's highly unlikely that sharepoint would add such functionality.

Comment: What does your HTML look like for these things?

Answer (score 0):

Clear value after alerting.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function PreSaveItem(){
        var result = true;
        var status=$("select[id*='Status_'] option:selected").text();
        if (status == "Closed") {
            var analysis = $('input[id^="Analysis_"]').val().trim();
            alert(analysis);
            alert(Date.now());
            if (analysis == "") {
                alert("Please Enter Analysis before closing the item");
                result = false;
                var analysis = undefined;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though clearly not getting what you are trying to achieve but would suggest you to update the method for selected text. It might work
suppose your select options are as follows

```
<select id="CountryName">
<option>India</option>
<option>Australia</option>
<option>England</option>
</select>
```

To get the selected text you can directly achieve selected text by:

```
var getSelected = $('#CountryName').find(":selected").text();
```